# I am looking for a way to read file with relative path in Spring boot project

Tags: java, spring-boot

The war I published reads absolute path.
I would like to read the file with relative path.

```
/at/tomcat/webapps/myapplication.war
/test.txt
```

I would like to

```
/at/tomcat/webapps/text.txt
```

How should I do?

JavaCode

```
File file = new File("./test.txt");
```

Tomcat status

```
tomcat-8080.service - Apatch tomcat8 server daemon
 Main PID: 5982 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   CGroup: /system.slice/tomcat-8080.service
           mq5990 /at/jdk/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/at/tomcat/tomcat-8080/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048 -Djava.protoc...

Using CATALINA_HOME:   /at/tomcat
1Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /at/tomcat/tomcat-8080/temp
1Using CLASSPATH:       /at/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/at/tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
1Using CATALINA_PID:    /at/tomcat/tomcat-8080/tomcat-8080.pid
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways for that

first manual

```
public Resource loadFile() {
    return new ClassPathResource("data/text.txt");
}
```

second way by using annotation

```
@Value("classpath:data/resource-data.txt")
Resource resourceFile;
```

there are other ways you can check the docs for details

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html

Comment: I changed below.
File file =  new ClassPathResource("./test.txt").getFile();  but it still  doesn't work.


java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource ["./test.txt"] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist

Comment: could you try to put the full path ? and if you are using linux make sure that the file got a permission RWX  .

Comment: it has already read files with full path  as```File file = new File("./test.txt");```  I would like it  to read files in the same directory.